# select image src inside a class

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I have the following list and I know the name of the class of the list

```
<div id="something">
 <ul>
  <li class="myClass1">
   <img src="img/Ace.png">
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I would just like to know the src of that image so I can put it in the blank source of the other. But when I tried to alert it, the path is undefined.

```
  var newimage = new Image();
    newimage.src = $(this).find(".match1").attr("src");
    alert(myimage);
    $("#image0").attr("src",newimage.src);
```

Comment: what is `.match1` & `#image0` its not in your code?

Comment: sorry it should be .find(".myClass1"), still not working

Comment: .match1 = .myClass1
and #image0 is an id of a blank <img>, <img src="" id="image0">

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#something .myClass1 img").each(function(k,v) {
    //If all you want is the src of the image, no need to make it into a jQuery object.
    var src = v.src; //Get the source.
    //Do something with it.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.myClass1 img').attr('src')
```

If you have multiple of these..

```
var temporary = "myClass1";
$('.' + temporary + ' img').each(function () {
    alert($(this).attr('src'));
});
```

EDIT:

You can use temporary var based on your comment - [jsFiddle Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/chaitu18mhyd/C7NA9/1/)

Comment: I put it in a variable:
var temporary = "myClass1";

$("."+temporary+"img").attr("src");
is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. var temporary = "myClass1"; $("." + temporary + " img").attr("src"); Remember to add the space before img.

Comment: what if I have multiple of class like that, does this still works? and I would just like to put it in a variable.

Comment: @gynophobia - I updated the fiddle example to work with multiple list items

Answer (score 0):

Try [`This`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/Ah55x/), this is helpful for you

If there are multiple image on it, You can use each loop like

```
$('.myClass1 img').each(function(){
    alert($(this).prop('src'));

})
```

Comment: What if there are multiple? It is in a class afterall.

Comment: then you can use each loop